# How to display the total size in MB

Tags: php

Just wondering if someone can help me out with this quickly.

I have a php script It works fine, However, I would like it to display the `Total Memory` in MB not in kb.

```
<div class="TitleBar">VM List</div>   

<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("host=".MGRCONFIG_DB_HOST."  port=".MGRCONFIG_DB_PORT." dbname=".MGRCONFIG_DB_NAME. " user=" .MGRCONFIG_DB_USER." password=".MGRCONFIG_DB_PASSWORD);
    if (!$conn) 
    {
        AddLog("vmlist.php","Could not connect to Database",ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);        
    }
    $query = "select guid,vmname,hostid,guestosname,cputype,cpucycle,totalmemory from vmobjects order by vmname";
    $result = pg_query($conn,$query);
    AddLog("vmlist.php","Query: ".$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $guid_array=Array();
    $lastname_array=Array();
    $firstname_array=Array();
    $osname_array=Array();
    $cptype_array=Array();
    $cpcycle_array=Array();
    $tom_array=Array();
    $no_of_record = 0;              

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
    {   
        $num_rows=0;
        $subquery = "select bussinessappid from bussinessapppolicyassoc where vmid ='".$row[0]."'";
        AddLog("vmlist.php","Query: ".$query,ERR_DEBUG_LOW);
        $subresult = pg_query($conn,$subquery);
        $num_rows=pg_num_rows($subresult);

        $guid_array[$no_of_record] = $row[0].'|'.$num_rows;
        $lastname_array[$no_of_record] = $row[1];

        $hostid = $row[2];
        $osname_array[$no_of_record] = $row[3];
        $cptype_array[$no_of_record] = $row[4];
        $cpcycle_array[$no_of_record] = $row[5];
        $tom_array[$no_of_record] = $row[6];                    

        $query = "select name from hosts where guid='".$hostid."'";
        $result1 = pg_query($conn,$query);
        AddLog("vmlist.php","Query: ".$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        while ($row1 = pg_fetch_array($result1)) 
        {
             $firstname_array[$no_of_record] = $row1[0];
        }                       
        $no_of_record++;                    
    }

    pg_close($conn);
?>
      <table class="objList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="vmtable">
        <tr>
          <td class="tbHeader"></td>
          <!--<td class="tbHeader"></td>
          <td class="tbHeader"></td>-->
          <td class="tbHeader">Name </td>
          <td class="tbHeader">Hostname</td>
          <td class="tbHeader">OS Name</td>
          <td class="tbHeader">CPU Type</td>
          <td class="tbHeader">CPU Cycle</td>
          <td class="tbHeader">Total Memory</td>




        </tr>
        <?php

            for ($i =0; $i < $no_of_record; $i++)
            {
                echo "<tr class=\"objList\" id=\"".$i."\">";

                echo "<td height=\"20\" width=\"25\" valign=\"top\" class=\"objList\">";

                //if(strcmp($_SESSION['mntvm_edit'],"1") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['mntvm_delete'],"1") == 0)
                {
                    echo "<img id=\"".$guid_array[$i]."\" src=\"images/icon-reports.gif\" alt=\"Options\" title=\"Options\" width=\"25\" height=\"20\" border=\"0\">";
                }
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$lastname_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$lastname_array[$i]."</td>";             

                echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$firstname_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$firstname_array[$i]."</td>";   

                echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$osname_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$osname_array[$i]."</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$cptype_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$cptype_array[$i]."</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$cpcycle_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$cpcycle_array[$i]."</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$tom_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$tom_array[$i]."</td>";

                echo "</tr>";                   
            }
            ?>
      </table>  
</div>
```

Comment: What is the total memory saved as in the database?

Comment: What is it in at the moment? Bytes?

Comment: @DaveRandom:) Question Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function kb_to_mb ($kb) {
  return $kb / 1024;
}
```

...and then...

```
...width=\"\">".kb_to_mb($tom_array[$i])."</td>"
```

...or just...

```
...width=\"\">".($tom_array[$i] / 1024)."</td>"
```

1 KB = 1024 Bytes
1 MB = 1024 KB
1 GB = 1024 MB
...etc, etc

You will probably want to [`round()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) the result to 1-2 decimal places.

Comment: `...width=\"\">".round($tom_array[$i] / 1024)."</td>"` - [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) rounds to the nearest integer, [`floor()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) rounds down and [`ceil()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) rounds up.

Comment: :) ya i can do it thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above, to go from KB to MB...

```
$MB = $numKBs / 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this should work. Change this line:

```
echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".$tom_array[$i]."\" width=\"\">".$tom_array[$i]."</td>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<td class=\"objList\" value=\"".round($tom_array[$i] / 1024, 2)."\" width=\"\">".round($tom_array[$i] / 1024, 2)."</td>";
```

This will output the number of megabytes, rounded to 2 decimal places.